# random header images ruby on rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I´m using the following code to randomize images in a header on a category page but I´m really not understanding why this method isn´t working.

it gives me this error `Invalid CSS after "...ackground: url(": expected ")", was "<%= randomized_..."`

in this line 
`#necklace_header {
    background: url(<%= randomized_header_image %>) no-repeat center center fixed;
    width: 100%;`

in my views/categories/show.html.erb I have this code

```
<header id="necklace_header">
<h1>
  <%= @category.name %>
</h1>
</header>



<%= render "categories/table", products: @products %>



<% if current_user && current_user.admin? %>
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_category_path(@category) %> |
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', root_path %>
```

In my categories.scss I have this piece of code

```
#necklace_header {
    background: url(<%= randomized_header_image %>) no-repeat center center fixed;
    width: 100%;


    background-size: cover;  

    height: 360px;
    margin-bottom: 20px; 

}
```

And in the application_helper.rb I got this code

```
module ApplicationHelper

    def randomized_header_image
        images = ["assets/foo.jpg", "assets/random.jpg", "assets/super_random"]
        images[rand(images.size)]
    end

end
```

since I´m pretty much a newbie to rails and web coding in general I have not been able to figure this out. I would be great if someone could clarify this for me.

Comment: ok u have `.scss`, so ERB code will not work. But try to right it like `asset-url('randomized_header_image')` . It will work. `asset-url` is SASS helper.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfectly now

Comment: I added it as answer. Thanks for confirming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As OP [confirmed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38772805/random-header-images-ruby-on-rails?noredirect=1#comment64917322_38772805) my suggestion worked. I am going to turn it back to an answer for future readers.

You have .scss file, so ERB code will not work. But try to write it like `asset-url('randomized_header_image')` and it should work. `asset-url` is SASS helper.